# How to create an RDS instance from the most recent snapshot or from scratch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, devops, terraform

In terraform, is there a way to conditionally create an RDS instance from the most recent snapshot of a given database or to create an empty database depending on the value of a parameter?

I tried something like that:

```
variable "db_snapshot_source" {
  default = ""
}

data "aws_db_snapshot" "last_snap" {
  count = "${var.db_snapshot_source == "" ? 0 : 1}"

  most_recent = true
  db_instance_identifier = "${var.db_snapshot_source}"
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "db" {
  [...]

  snapshot_identifier = "${var.db_snapshot_source == "" ? "" : data.aws_db_snapshot.last_snap.db_snapshot_identifier}"
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work because TF seems to dereference `data.aws_db_snapshot.last_snap` even if the ternary is false. I get the following error message: `* aws_db_instance.db: Resource 'data.aws_db_snapshot.last_snap' not found for variable 'data.aws_db_snapshot.last_snap.db_snapshot_identifier'`.

How can I achieve a such behaviour? The only option I see is to declare two aws_db_instance resources each with opposed `count` which is horrifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defining a count you are saying the result of the data resource will be a list even if it is a zero value.

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "db" {
  [...]

  snapshot_identifier = "${
    var.db_snapshot_source == "" ? "" : 
    element(
      concat(data.aws_db_snapshot.last_snap.*.db_snapshot_identifier, list("")), 0)
  }"
}
```

The concat is required if you expect the list to be empty. Otherwise you get an error

`element: element() may not be used with an empty list...`

[Github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11210) describing the concat behaviour

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html#snapshot_identifier) reads as though specifying `snapshot_identifier` is what triggers using a snapshot or not, so passing in an empty string is not enough to avoid starting from a snapshot. In that case, you would need two `aws_rds_instance` resources, and then have ternary expressions for `count` on each resource to decide which one to create. As you mentioned, this is horrifying, but it might work ok.

Another way to think about it is if you had a blank snapshot in your inventory to start from. Then it's just a ternary operator away from deciding to use the custom snapshot or this blank snapshot. I don't know that you can create a blank snapshot in Terraform though, it's creation might be out of band.